# Reverse the digits of a number using a list

Tags: scheme

I would like to reverse the numbers of a digit by using a list in Scheme. So far my logic is to get the modulo of the number by 10 and append that number to a list. In each recursive call the number is decreased by dividing it by 10. So far my code is the following:

```
(define (reverse n L)
 (let ((r (remainder n 10)))
    (if (= n 0)
        L
        (begin
          ((append L (list r))
           (reverse (/ n 10) L))))))
```

The problem that I got is when I input a value, for example 123, is the following:

```
remainder: contract violation
  expected: integer?
  given: 123/10
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scheme when you divide two integers, in the result you get integer or *ratio*. `123/10` is a ratio (because you can't divide 123 by 10 and get integer).

If you want to convert it to integer, you have to `floor` or `ceil` it.

Answer (score 0):

The better approach would be to use `quotient` (`truncate-quotient` in R7RS, though the older name is kept for backwards compatibility), which does integer division with truncation:

```lisp
scheme@(guile-user)> (/ 123 10)
$1 = 123/10
scheme@(guile-user)> (quotient 123 10)
$2 = 12
scheme@(guile-user)> (truncate-quotient 123 10) ; R7RS name
$3 = 12
```

R7RS also has `floor-quotient`, and if your scheme supports [SRFI-141](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-141/srfi-141.html) you have even more options for how the result is calculated in non-exact cases. R6RS has a few other varieties as well.

There are also versions that return both the quotient and remainder together, which can be more efficient than separate uses:

```lisp
scheme@(guile-user)> (truncate/ 123 10)
$4 = 12
$5 = 3
```

letting you write your function as something like

```lisp
(import (scheme base))
(define (reverse-number n)
  (let loop ((n n)
             (digits '()))
    (if (= n 0)
        (reverse digits)
        (let-values (((q r) (truncate/ n 10)))
          (loop q (cons r digits))))))

(reverse-number 123) ; (3 2 1)
```